# GTK Obtain "external app" GtkClipboard "owner" (Windows)

Tags: winapi, gtk

Have created a Gtk based app.  It can Cut/Copy/Paste (CCP) "internally" and across to/from other apps via the `GtkClipboard`.

One concern arise when CCP'ing from an another app into ours, say from Excel or Firefox, into ours.  Out Gtk code can determine the full list of available "formats" (i.e. Atoms/Targets) that each external app is capable for providing.

That list, of course, depends on the "owner app" (i.e. where the CCP originated).

Unfortunately, we can't find a way to determine the actual "owner app" that send/owns the CCP'd material.  For example, we can't figure out if it came from Excel of Firefox (of course one can analyse the last of Atoms/Targets and have a "guess" (e.g. if the Atoms/Targets include BIFF's, its probably from a spreadsheet etc.

What is actually required is a direct and explicit way to obtain the "owner app".  That is, if the CCP came from "Excel", then we should be able to (hopeful) use some Gtk strategy to extract that information.

It appears to be possible with pyGkt, and possibly only on X, such seen on this page (http://commonsmachinery.se/2013/07/copy-paste-linux/) where the clipboard owner returns the "app" (e.g. Firefox, etc).

Is that also possible with standard Gtk+?   We note:

1) the following:

```
gtk_clipboard_get_owner (GtkClipboard *clipboard);
```

is not of much help, if we understood it correctly, since it returns only "owners" that are actually set explicitly within Gtk (e.g. by

```
gtk_clipboard_set_text (GtkClipboard *clipboard, const gchar *text, gint len);
```

etc.

Yes, we have tested the code, it doesn't work (or at least not in the sense we would like it).  Have tried many variations directly with the different types of callbacks (since different callbacks provide different data).  For example "owner-change" provide GtkSelectionData, but the "owner" component of that is just the Atom/Target of the owner ... and so on, and so forth, with many permutations/combinations (e.g. request_content(), request_target(), etc etc, each with their specific callbacks).

So is it possible in standard Gtk, and on Windows, to determine the explicit name of the "ownder" of the selection on the clipboard, or is it only available, say, on pyGtk on X etc  ... we fear we may have missed something all too simple?

Please advise.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Windows has no concept of a "clipboard owner" like X11 does, and that on Windows clipboard contents are system-global and copied from the process that sets the clipboard to another part of memory (so clipboard contents survive past the end of execution). But I'm not fully sure. I've added the winapi tag to this question; hopefully someone there can clear the issue up as well.

Answer (score 0):

OK, we think we have arrived at "one answer", though it is not very satisfactory (but it may be as good as it gets).

CAVEAT:  we are "end users/math geeks", not "developers/IT geeks", and would invite Gtk and WinAPI "Gods" to comment/verify.

The "answer":

1) Taking together our research prior to posting, andlabs comments above, and more research since ... we believe that Gtk CANNOT actually determine the App from which the current clipboard's content originate.

2) That looks fairly likely the case on Windows, and it seems that perhaps even on Linux, Gtk does not have such means.

We corresponded with Jonas (the author of this page (http://commonsmachinery.se/2013/07/copy-paste-linux/) cited above) where it seemed that Gtk (at least pyGtk) did manage this.  In fact, it did not.  Jonas wrote to us with:

"this isn't a feature of neither pyGtk or anything other Gtk. It's merely making use of the Xlib method get_wm_name(). Whether Windows has something similar in its equivalent of Xlib, I'm afraid that we do not know."

3) Accepting that Gtk can't do it, we took andlabs indication and Jonas' comments that we would need to look to the WinAPI for our solution.  We did the following:

a) Create a standard `GtkClipboard` signal for "owner-change".

b) In the callback function for that signal we inserted (first creating the appropriate "interface blocks" to the WinAPI function) a couple of WinAPI functions, namely of the form:

```
OwnerHandle = GetClipboardOwner()   ! GetClipboardOwner() is the WinAPI for the "Windows HANDLE" of the current clipboard ownder
```

We could not find a WinAPI that returned the "app" that owns the current clipboard.  The best we could find is a WinAPI that returns the "Title" of the Window from which the "bits" were Cut/Copy'd, which is the function GetWindowText().

Unfortunately, the OwnerHandle could be the Handle of a "child window" in the owner app, as we discovered from the comments of Syed Waqas  at this SO posting ([Get Clipboard owners Title/Caption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023754/get-clipboard-owners-title-caption)).  So, we wrote a loop that checked if the "current owner Handle" is a child, by implementing the WinAPI GetParent(), creating code that roughly looks like this (we have aliased the WinAPI routines to have local names that begin with "w32_" etc., and this example omits the overloading of both ANSI and UNICODE, showing only the ANSI variant) :

```
!
w32_GetClipboardOwner_Test = w32_GetClipboardOwner()
w32_GetClipboardOwner_cInt = w32_GetClipboardOwner_Test
!
Do While ( w32_GetClipboardOwner_Test > 0_c_IntPtr_t )
    !
    w32_GetClipboardOwner_Test = w32_GetParent(w32_GetClipboardOwner_Test)
    !
    ! the "If" portion of the next line may be pedantic 
    ! with some compilers/languages, 
    If( w32_GetClipboardOwner_Test > 0_c_IntPtr_t ) w32_GetClipboardOwner_cInt = w32_GetClipboardOwner_Test
    !
End Do
!
! Get length of text in buffer, ir there is a valid Handle
!
If( w32_GetClipboardOwner_cInt > 0_c_IntPtr_t ) Then
    w32_GetWindowText_nAct_cInt = w32_GetWindowTextLengthA(w32_GetClipboardOwner_cInt)
End If
!
! get the text (window title) and put in the buffer implied by lpString
!
w32_GetWindowText_nAct_cInt = w32_GetWindowTextA(hWnd = w32_GetClipboardOwner_cInt, &
                                            lpString = w32_GetWindowText_Str_cPtr, &
                                            nMaxCount = w32_GetWindowText_nMax_cInt)
```

, where the type c_IntPtr_t has been stated to form an "equivalent" to the Windows HANDLE "pointer/entity", at least for these purposes (yes, we know it's more complicated compared to traditional pointer, but likely not an issue here, as suggested by other sources).

Unfortunately, and as indicated by Syed Waqas, even with this extra care, there is no guarantee that the owner can be identified, since it is possible for apps to own data on the clipboard without having a "connection" to their "Window Title".

Bizarrely, none of the "big name apps" actually worked in this process (e.g. Excel, Word, FireFox, etc.), whereas many "no name" apps at least return the "app.exe" or "something".

We also discovered that MS Office also has the OfficeClipboard, and the OLEClipboard, which "attaches itself" to the "standard" clipboard somehow.  We don't know how that works, and could use some much appreciated help.

Of course, we were looking the get the "owner app" (not some window title), but this is as far as we got toward "a not so satisfactory solution".

This is rather unsatisfactory for us, since for example, once there has been a Cut/Copy, the Paste step has many possibilities based on all the formats (Atoms/Targets) the clipboard data can be converted to.  While we have written a "Paste Special" routine to list all the Targets, so the user can choose the format of the Paste, we were looking to be able to provide a "default" choice, but which (of course) would depend on the owner App (e.g. the default for Excel CCP might be BIFF8 or XML etc, while for Notepad, UTF8 etc.)

The Excel connection is a bit more important for our specific Gtk app, since it too has spreadsheet component, and would like to be able to CCP between Excel and our Gtk spreadsheet in a sensible manner.

ASIDE: A question for the SO moderators.  As this issue has now morphed from a `GtkClipboard` matter to a WinAPI/OLE etc matter, should we post a new question purely in the WinAPI context, and with the new issues?